# UINavigationController, simply hiding the navigation bar

Tags: objective-c

I've I have a simple noob question, I would like to hide the navigation bar of a UINavigationController, but I'm pretty sure I`m not calling the right object .

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[TestViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    viewController = [ [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window addSubview: rootViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Now, I`ve tried, this :

```
-(void)hideBar {


    viewController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

It is complaining that "navigationBarHidden" not found on object type UIViewController, obviously I would need to call the UINavigation controller instead, but that's where I'm stuck ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

within your TestViewController. A good place is in `viewDidLoad`

Also, while we're at it, remove the line `[window addSubview:rootViewController.view];`, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

In Navigation controller's root view controller's method viewDidLoad write this -

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
```

in your case its TestViewController.